__published not recognized as access modifier in clang-format-12 linux version
I have a C++Builder project.
In this project, I need to verify code formatting using clang-format-12.
When I run format on save in Windows part (clang-format version 12.0.1 (git@ngnu:llvm-project e904e87151344c417b7cb6da3e125febfc395e53)), the __published access modifier is indented as I want (using AccessModifierOffset: -4).
In a Jenkins server, I have constructed a Linux docker with clang-format-12 (Debian clang-format version 12.0.1-++20211216045758+fed41342a82f-1~exp1~20211216170241.12).
When I run clang-format-12 in this Linux docker to verify code formatting, it says to me that the code is not well formatted.
To see the difference, I auto-format the code with my docker, after windows clang-format the code is:
class TFormFilesAsk : public TForm
{
__published: // Composants gérés par l'EDI
    TPanel *Panel1;
    TLabel *LabelFile1;
    TPanel *PanelFileNameEdition1;

And at the end of Linux docker clang format, the code became:
class TFormFilesAsk : public TForm
{
    __published : // Composants gérés par l'EDI
                  TPanel *Panel1;
    TLabel *LabelFile1;
    TPanel *PanelFileNameEdition1;

I think it is because the __published access modifier is not recognized, but only in the Linux part.
Does anyone have an idea of any setting in clang-format to fix this?
I have tried to change my Linux docker to a Windows docker with clang-format, but without success.

__published is a C++Builder language extension, it is recognized only by C++Builder compilers, and those compilers are available only on Windows.

yes i know but clang format on windows can recognize it, is there a solution to declare __published as an access modifier in .clang-format file ? or any other solution ?
